# how can I add click sounds to :active when my site is viewed on ipad and iphone?

Tags: jquery, audio, touch, screen

css animations and transitions sure are great - but they have no effect on :hover when using a touchscreen device (such as an ipad) --- which sorta takes some of the fun out.

I would like to add a simple sound to the :active state of some buttons to give my users a little more satisfaction when clicking links while using a touch screen... but I don't want to build a special app for each site... Does anyone have any suggestions for me ?  Is there a way to do this with just html and css and maybe jQuery ?

Comment: `when clicking links while using a touch screen` The idea behind touch-based devices is that *there is no clicking*. You shouldn't be providing feedback for an event that doesn't exist. And you should consider that your users don't want to hear random clicking sounds — if they did, they would be using IE.

Comment: I hate it when sites play sounds!

Comment: I am pretty sure you guys are misunderstanding me.  I'm not trying to get sounds all over the place... like a 90s flash site...  Have you ever used the keyboard on your iPad?  well, i find those sounds that happen (when i press the keys) to be useful.  If you aren't trying to help answer this question... then please don't waist your time commenting on this thread.